# How to calculate percentile or ranking of a value in a collection?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, algorithm, percentile

I have a collection of about 8,000 test scores in an XML file.
Using Linq and C#, what is one of the most efficient ways to calculate the percentile of a particular test score.

My emphasis is on **efficiency**. So what is the recommended approach? I am also looking for the appropriate builtin Linq or C# functions recommended for this calculation. Is there something called Percentile() or TopPercent?

Comment: Well, the most expensive thing here is to parse your xml into inmemory objects. Calculations of inmemory numbers are really fast. 8000 records are not many. Just use standard approaches. Map your xml to some classes then make calculations, or just do everything in just one Linq2XML query.

Comment: Could you show a sample XML fragment as well as what values you are interested in?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov <student><history>88</history><math>23</math>...</student>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're worrying about efficiency before you've verified that you *need* to worry about it.

I would take the following approach:

- Load the XML file into memory with LINQ to XML (as the simplest XML API in .NET)
- Convert the scores into a list of integers (or whatever the score type is)
- You can now find out the total count easily
- Use `Count` with a predicate to find out how many scores are less than your "target" score

If you need to check multiple scores, you obviously *only* need to repeat the final step.

My *first* attempt at optimizing this (for multiple checks) would be to sort the list, so you can then just do a binary search to find the rank of each score. I'd only go *that* far after benchmarking though.